# Get id of file upload control

Tags: file-upload

I am trying to find the name of ID of the input item that coresponds to the
file that is being uploaded...

```
<input type="file" id="FUtxtval1" name="FUtxtval1"/>
```

Comment: It's "FUtxtval1". But you probably knew that anyway, so care to ask a question?

Comment: You're trying to get the id using PHP or JavaScript? Are you trying to get the id or the filename?

Comment: I think this question is asking about the ID of the uploaded file, not the actual control, but it depends entirely on the scripting language used? http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html

Comment: I m trying to get Id in Javascript

Comment: Ask a more descriptive question if you genuinely want answers.

Comment: Is this in ASP.NET Forms? If so the ID might get prefixed with IDs of containing objects. In recent ASP.NET Forms there are attributes to force a fixed, unprefixed ID or you can make the control runat="server" then use .ClientID on same-named property on your page class to get the generated ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iterating over input items to find the first file input field:

```
function FindFirstFileFieldId()
{
    var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for(var i=0;i<inputFields.length;i++)
    {
      if(inputFields[i].type=="file")
        return inputFields[i].id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The ID of the element is simply "FUtxtval1" (whatever is in the ID tag)

--

For JavaScript you can access this by using

```
var element = document.getElementById('FUtxtval1');
```

So you could then do something like

```
document.element.disabled=true;
```

--

For jQuery (Also JavaScript) you would use

```
$('#FUtxtval1').whatever
```

--

For PHP you would use

```
$_POST['FUtxtval1']
```

Assuming this is part of a form

For PHP if you actually want the file you use the handle

```
$_FILES['FUtxtval1']['whateverwanted'];
```

See http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that there may be many `input` tags on the form, and you're interested in discovering which one is specifically used for uploading files, this bit of jQuery code would accomplish that:

```
var id = $('input[type=file]').attr('id');
```

If the problem is that you know the element's ID but do not know the name of the field, you can use:

```
var name = $('#FUtxtval1').attr('name');
```

If you're hoping to find out the filename of the file your visitor has chosen in that field through JavaScript, you're stuck. JavaScript does not get any access to that information. You'll have to submit the form and let a server-side script determine the filename at that time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to obtain the id of the uploaded file using javascript? If so, you will have to process the uploaded file using php ($_FILES['FUtxtval1']) and then print the id to a javascript variable.

Is that what you wanted?

If not, update your q to provide a bit more info about what you are trying to achieve.